# Decide if $X(t)$ is a Gaussian random process.

Tags: stochastic-processes, random

Let $X(t)$ be a wide-sense stationary (WSS) random process with the autocorrelation function $R_{XX} = \sigma^2 e^{-\alpha \tau^2}$. Is $X(t)$ a Gaussian random process?

---

Here is my try:
A random process $Y(t)$ is a Gaussian random process if the samples $Y_1 = Y(t_1), Y_2 = Y(t_2), ..., Y_k=Y(t_k)$ are joint Gaussian random variables for all $k$, and all choices of $t_1, ..., t_k$:
$$f_{Y_1, Y_2, ..., Y_k}(y_1, ..., y_k)=\frac{e^{-1/2(\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{m})^T \mathbf{K}^{-1} (\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{m})}}{(2\pi)^{k/2} |\mathbf{K}|^{1/2}}, \tag{1}$$
where
$$\mathbf{m} =
\begin{bmatrix}
m_Y(t_1) \\
\vdots \\
m_Y(t_k)
\end{bmatrix},
\mathbf{K} =
\begin{bmatrix}
C_Y(t_1, t_1) & C_Y(t_1, t_2) & \cdots & C_Y(t_1, t_k) \\
C_Y(t_2, t_1) & C_Y(t_2, t_2) & \cdots & C_Y(t_2, t_k) \\
\vdots & \vdots & & \vdots \\
C_Y(t_k, t_1) & \cdots & & C_Y(t_k, t_k)
\end{bmatrix}, \tag{2}$$
where
$$C_Y(t_i, t_j) = R_Y(t_i, t_j) - m_Y(t_i) m_Y(t_j), 1 \leq i, j\leq k, \tag{3}$$
and $R_Y(t_i, t_j)$ is the autocorrelation function of $Y(t)$.

Then
\begin{align}
C_X(t_1, t_2) & = R_X(t_1, t_1) - m_X(t_1) m_X(t_1) \\
& = R_{XX}(0) - [m_X(t_1)]^2 \\
& = \sigma^2 - [m_X(t_1)]^2. \tag{4}
\end{align}

Then I don't know how to continue.

Comment: What do you think the answer is? What is your conjecture? What have you looked at? I would start from "Are gaussian processes characterized by the property that their auto-correlation function is gaussian?" If so, good; if not, what are other examples and how does this bear on your problem?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have added my try after the question.

Comment: @uniquesolution No, Gaussian process has no such characterization. The correct one is, given any positive semidefinite correlation function, there is a corresponding Gaussian process. As for the original problem, there is no sufficient detail to assert whether $X(t)$ is Gaussian or not. It can either be or not be Gaussian.

Comment: @CaveJohnson - so why don't you provide a counter-example and grab the 50 points?